# How does the Sorcerer's Draconic Power feature work?

Tags: dnd-4e, class-feature, sorcerer

I want to make a Sorcerer with the Dragon Magic feature, but I need to know if the + Strength Modifier is in addition to the + Charisma Modifier to the damage or instead of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**In addition to your charisma modifier.**

From the Compendium:

> **Draconic Power:** You gain a bonus to the damage rolls of arcane powers equal to your Strength modifier. The bonus increases to your Strength modifier +2 at 11th level and your Strength modifier +4 at 21st level.

It is a bonus. It does not replace any existing boosts to damage.

Comment: Just wanted to add: All of the striker characters have some sort of "striker feature" that adds damage to their attacks: Rogues get Sneak Attack, Rangers get Hunter's Quarry, Warlocks get their curses, Assassins get shrouds, and Monks and Bladesingers get extra attacks after they hit. Sorcerers and some other characters get a simple flat-value ability-score bonus to their damage. Sometimes these bonuses (especially the ability score-dependent ones) are selected based on your class features, which is what is happening here.